# Matrix whose coefficients are functions

Tags: functions, matrix

What is the right way to declare of matrix whose coefficients are functions of a variable $x$ ?

I tried :

```
Table[Table[a[i,j][x_],{j,1,NN}],{i,1,NN}]
```

Comment: You can not use `N` as a variable change it..

Comment: ok that was not the problem

Comment: What about sth. like this: `Table[Table[a[i, j, x_], {j, 1, 2}], {i, 1, 2}]`

Comment: And what about `Table[a[i, j][x_], {i, 1, NN}, {j, 1, NN}]` ?  Why two calls to `Table` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_, n_] := Table[Table[a[i, j, x], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]
```

for example

```
f[x, 4] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's worth knowing about the `Array` function which might be used like this:

```
Array[a[#1, #2][x_] &, {4, 4}]
```

This reproduces the output of OP's initial version (with `NN` set to `4`).  I'm not convinced that that is really what OP wants, so this variation

```
Array[a[#1, #2, x_] &, {4, 4}]
```

might also appeal.